# Get each JSON array value using PHP

Tags: arrays

I've been trying to read this JSON with PHP:

```
{
    "total_found":"49",
    "1":{
        "title":"Maze Runner-The Scorch Trials 2015 HD-TS x264-Garmin",
        "category":"video",
        "seeds":2141,
        "leechs":1176,
        "torrent_size":1122230176,
        "torrent_hash":"29d3e7062825a62abdd877ee96dc3fea41183836"
    },
    "2":{
        "title":"Maze.Runner-The.Scorch.Trials.2015.720P.HD-TS.x264.AC3.HQ.Hive-CM8",
        "category":"hdrip",
        "seeds":395,
        "leechs":1856,
        "torrent_size":3999751475,
        "torrent_hash":"e1e14a5ccf540a739907db2e1e0d810ecdb8bebc"
    }
}
```

How can I get each `title` and `torrent_size`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to decode the JSON to an array. PHP has a built-in function for this:

```
$results = json_decode($json_data);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

To clearly see the array structure, try dumping the variable `$results` using `print_r();`, i.e.:

```
print_r($results);
```

Then you simply need to access the data using the array.

It will be something like `$results[1]['torrent_size'];`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped.